# Mac App Store Sample Receipt... Where Is It?

Tags: objective-c, macos, validation

I'm adding some features to a pre-existing mac app that uses receipt verification.  The way the app was coded, it relied on Apple's sample receipt to be on the desktop (for debugging).  The URL that the receipt used to be at now redirects to a different page.  Where can I get this sample receipt?!

Old URL:
http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/validating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW21

**UPDATE**

For future internet surfers looking for the answer.

I found it at this url:
http://images.worldofapple.com/validating_051110.pdf

You'll have to format the text before creating a usable receipt.  TextWrangler with a find and replace of "\r\r" -> "\r" did the trick.  Also, do that off the HTML representation.  The PDF version is all gunked up.